# angular tags selected in to input

Tags: angularjs, tags

I would like to display tags and when user clicks on each one, the tag color will change, and to have all the selected tags inside a hidden input for future submiting.

You could view the starting of the code inside: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bq2JAqSAahQl6lWDVWvC?p=preview

the html:

```
<div ng-controller="TagsSelectCtrl">
  <div class="label label-default">man</div>
  <div class="label label-default">woman</div>
  <div class="label label-default">boys</div>
  <div class="label label-default">girls</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use `ng-repeat` to create the tags like below,

**in controller**

```
$scope.tags = ['man', 'woman', 'boys', 'girls'];
```

**in HTML**

```
<div class="label label-default" ng-repeat="tag in tags" 
     ng-click="clicked = !clicked; add(tag, clicked)" 
     ng-class="{'clicked-color': clicked}">

        {{ tag }}

  </div>
```

if click on the tag then first it create a `clicked` variable in  the `ng-repeat`'s scope and toggle the value of `clicked`, and then call a `add` function in the controller,

at the controller,

```
 $scope.add = function(item, clicked) {
  // if click is true then add a item to choosed tags
  if(clicked) {
    $scope.choseTags.push(item);
  } else {
    if click is false then remove the added item from the choosed tags
    var index = $scope.choseTags.indexOf(item);

    $scope.choseTags.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

and finally `ng-class`

```
...ng-class="{'clicked-color': clicked}"
```

if `clicked` is true then `clicked-color` `css` class add to the element

here is the [live DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/oGGHl2HoW2Hu9j55dPiV?p=preview)

Comment: it worked great! but is there way to minimize the use of the tags inside the html? like all the ifs and "clicked = !clicked; add(tag, clicked)" things?